# Implementing google analytics in epi server

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   
$("#sideBarRedeemButton").click(function(){

ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'button',
  eventAction: 'click',
  eventLabel: 'Kod reg'
});

});
```

Comment: Will this code work? which is correct way to send events to GA?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Analytics documentation on tracking Events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) code should work. Just check your browser Developer tools Console and Network tabs.